# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5

On my webpage, there is an error that bootstrap-sprockets cannot be imported. All the css was working fine just a minute ago. I added styled my signup page error messages and all of a sudden bootstrap-sprockets stopped working.

**custom.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

$gray-medium-light: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing:         border-box;
}
.
.
.

/* forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

input {
  height: auto !important;
}
#error_explanation {
  color: red;
  ul {
    color: red;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  }
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
  .form-control {
    color: $state-danger-text;
  }
}
```

**custom.css**

```
 /*
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
        on line 1 of         /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss

1: @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
2: @import "bootstrap";
3: 
4: $gray-medium-light: #eaeaea;
5: 
6: @mixin box_sizing {

Backtrace:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss:1
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:313:in `visit_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in `block in visit_children'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in `visit_children'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in `visit_root'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:29:in `render_with_sourcemap'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/engine.rb:381:in `_render_with_sourcemap'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/engine.rb:298:in `render_with_sourcemap'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:492:in `update_stylesheet'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:215:in `block in update_stylesheets'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `update_stylesheets'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/plugin.rb:82:in `update_stylesheets'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:340:in `watch_or_update'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:51:in `process_result'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:52:in `parse'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:19:in `parse!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/bin/scss:13:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/scss:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/scss:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
*/
body:before {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
  content: "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.\A         on line 1 of /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss\A \A 1: @import \"bootstrap-sprockets\";\A 2: @import \"bootstrap\";\A 3: \A 4: $gray-medium-light: #eaeaea;\A 5: \A 6: @mixin box_sizing {"; }
```

**gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.0.1'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'
gem 'bcrypt',         '3.1.11'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.12'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**I have tried restarting the server. Like I said, the bootstrap was working perfectly until I updated my scss with my #error_explanation styles for my signup page form. I tried bundle installing and bundle updating and restarting the server once more but I am getting the same error on my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add your SCSS imports to your application.css.scss and then below that import your custom.scss

```
// app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom";
```